# Clamping by image shape: replace X,Y coordinates by different rules in Numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, opencv

I have a picture of shape (225, 400, 3) and a set of x,y coordinates:

```py
polygon = np.array([[150, 80], [350, 80], [420, 280], [350, 250], [150, 250]], np.int32)
```

I want to clamp those values to dimensions of my image, so any given pair of coordinates won't be outside of my image. This means that I need to replace all x-coordinates `[X > 400, ...]` with 400 and all y-coordinates `[..., Y > 225]` with 225.

I tried to replace all Y coordinates greater than 255 without success, it also clamps X coordinates.

```py
polygon[(polygon > 225).all(axis=1)] = 225
```

What's the correct way of clamping Numpy array values by different rules in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC and by coordinates you mean that each row contains a `(x,y)` coordinate (note that this is not the same as `axis`), then you can index and use [`clip`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.clip.html):

```
polygon[:,0] = polygon[:,0].clip(max=400)
polygon[:,1] = polygon[:,1].clip(max=255)
```

---

```
print(polygon)

array([[150,  80],
       [350,  80],
       [400, 255],
       [350, 250],
       [150, 250]])
```

Comment: Brillian! Exactly this! Tried to use advanced indexing, but this is much more elegant!

Comment: Btw timeit with 10,000,000 iterations: 3.552 sec for `clip()` and 3.558 sec for `where()`!

Answer (score 0):

You can use np.where:

```
polygon[:,0]  = np.where(polygon[:,0] > 400, 400, polygon[:,0])
polygon[:,1]  = np.where(polygon[:,1] > 225, 225, polygon[:,1])
```

You will obtain the next output:

```
array([[150,  80],
       [350,  80],
       [400, 225],
       [350, 225],
       [150, 225]])
```

Comment: Thank you for suggestion! Could you please tell if there any time complexity, etc. advantages in `where()` over `clip()` approach?

Comment: I have just computed both expressions in my computer and the outputs are: np.where Wall time: 270 µs and np.clip Wall time: 1.56 ms. So its faster the np.where approach.

Comment: Interesting, did you use timeit?

Comment: Got pretty impressive results using timeit with 10,000,000 iterations: 3.552 sec for `clip()` and 3.558 sec for `where()`. Both ways are really fast!

Comment: Guess that both using numpy are pretty much the same. Hope it helped and thanks for your research using timeit!